# How to show $b^t < b^r$ for $b>1$, if $t < r$ and both are rationals, using only basic tools of analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation

Assume I have only read chapter 1 of Rudin up to exercise 6b). So we are still proving the properties of exponentiation and don't know how to fully manipulate exponents. Right now I am stuck showing the following (:

$$ \text{ if } t < r \implies b^t < b^r $$

where $b>1$ and $t,r \in \mathbb{Q}$

I know it's "obvious" because exponentiation is monotone (which can be easily shown since its derivative is positive, though we have not defined derivatives so that makes no sense as a justification just yet). Thus, I was wondering how one goes about proving the above statement.

What I attempted was to re-write exponents of rationals with the tools that we **do** know. We know $b^{t} = b^{t_1/t_2} = \left( b^{t_1} \right)^{\frac{1}{t_2}} = \left( b^{\frac{1}{t_2}} \right)^{t_1}$ and $b^{r} = b^{r_1/r_2} = \left( b^{r_1} \right)^{\frac{1}{r_2}} = \left( b^{\frac{1}{r_2}} \right)^{r_1}$ so I re-wrote it as follows:

$$ \left( b^{r_1} \right)^{\frac{1}{r_2}} \text{ vs } \left( b^{t_1} \right)^{\frac{1}{t_2}}$$

and raise both expression to the $t_2 r_2$ which yielded:

$$ b^{t_1 r_2} \leq b^{r_1 t_2}$$

since $t_1 r_2 \leq r_1 t_2$. This is obviously correct because both the exponents are just natural numbers and $b>1$ so nothing fishy is going on. However, its unclear how that implies what I want, specially because taking roots of both since (which is tempting to do just take $1/r_2$ root of both sides and then do that with $t_2$) and voila you would "get the answer". But taking roots of both sides and hoping the inequality keep holding is exactly what I am having trouble proving. Is there something I am missing? I am fine with the answer but I am also happy with hints (and maybe hide the answer?)?

---

EDIT:

I just notice that:

$$t_1 r_2 \leq r_1 t_2$$

is not necessarily true. We know $r,t \in \mathbb{Q}$ but we don't know if the denominators or numerators are negative or not or if $r,t$ themselves are negative, so we don't know if there are any weird sign shifts when playing with the inequality.

Comment: Assume $b^t>b^r$ and conclue $t_1r_2\ge r_1t_2$, contradiction

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have to advise caution on the fact that the negation of $t<r$ is not $t>r$.

Comment: @KennyLau I am getting confused on the suggestions. Are you saying that Hagen's suggestion is incorrect?

Comment: If $r, t$ are rational then the proof is algebraic and simple and perhaps presented in textbooks where one learns of rational exponents. No tools from analysis are needed here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the above question is nearly equivalent to showing $b^r = \sup B(r)$ where $B(r) = \{ b^t : t \in \mathbb{Q}, t \leq r \}$. I am deriving everything from first principles, no cheating and saying things like "its obvious" unless its an axiom.

Comment: And I can understand your situation and the reason is precisely Rudin's book, which just over complicates simple stuff in the name of rigor. In reality Rudin emphasizes mostly formalism and not rigor.

Comment: Also the definition $b^{r} = \sup\, \{b^{t} \mid t\in \mathbb{Q}, t<r\} $ is one of the definitions for $b^{r} $ when $r$ is irrational. And to show that this definition makes sense you just need to show that the set is bounded above. And this requires the result in question here. But the result in  question does not in anyway depend on the definition of $b^{r} $ involving $\sup$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh what proof did you have in mind for rationals that was just "algebraic and simple"? Maybe you can provide a better answer than the ones already provided.

Comment: I have already given answer in comments, but on your request I provide an answer with more details.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh maybe I am being really pedantic, but I guess Im not sure why everything is so obvious if one really try to start from first principles...I thought there was a whole book proving 1+1=2 or something, maybe Im too dense. Thanks regardless.

Comment: Rightly said. It is only when one works via first principles that things start to look obvious. Unfortunately most math textbooks don't work in that manner (by using that cheap sentence "the proof is beyond the scope of the book") and hence most of math is perceived as tough and almost mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider:$$t<r \Rightarrow \exists x \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0} : t<r = t+x $$

Now the inequality to be proved becomes:

$$b^t<b^r\Rightarrow b^t<b^{r} = b^{t+x} \Rightarrow b^t<b^t\cdot b^x \Rightarrow 1<b^x.$$

Finally, raising both sides to the power $\frac1x$ (note that $x>0 \Rightarrow\frac1x>0)$ we get:

$$b>1.$$

Comment: raising both side to the power of $1/x$ is the exact property I am trying to show. How do you do that if we don't know that function is monotone?

Comment: wait why do you want to raise both sides to the power of $1/x$? that seems rather random to me. I think you already have the proof that I was looking for.

Comment: we start with $t<r \implies t<t+\epsilon, t,r,\epsilon \in \mathbb Q$. Then we just note that $b^r = b^{t+\epsilon}=b^t b^{\epsilon}$. Since $b>1$ then we have $b^t b^{\epsilon} $ must have increased, which completes the proof, no?

Answer (score 4):

I will present a framework. Here, the "stronger theorem" is the theorem with "if" replaced by "if and only if"

### 1. Prove that the stronger theorem is true on natural numbers by induction.

This should be the most tedious part of the process, but I will leave that to you. Note that $b$ is still an arbitrary rational number.

### 2. Prove that the stronger theorem is true on integers.

This would require using the **definition** of negative power as the reciprocal of positive power, and then using some basic theorems (or axioms) of ordering. Note that $b$ is still an arbitrary rational number.

### 3. Prove that the theorem is true on rational numbers.

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
b^t &<& b^r \\
(b^t)^{t_2~r_2} &<& (b^r)^{t_2~r_2} & \text{by 2} \\
b^{t_1~r_2} &<& b^{t_2~r_1} \\
t_1 r_2 &<& t_2 r_1 & \text{by 2} \\
t &<& r
\end{array}$$

Comment: kenny I appreciate your attempt to help me, sorry if this is a dense question maybe I am missing the bigger picture but how does your suggestion prove what I need even if I were to do it? Maybe I don't really understand what your suggesting me to do.

Comment: @Pinocchio I'm suggesting you to prove the theorem on the integers first, and then use that to prove the theorem on the rationals.

Comment: This is the typical simple / algebraic proof which I mentioned in comments to question. +1 for nice exposition in step by step manner.

Answer (score 2):

So you see that it suffices to show that  $1 < b \leq c$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ implies $b^{1/n} \leq c^{1/n}$. Assume to the contrary that $b^{1/n} > c^{1/n}$. Then raising both sides to the power of $n$ yields $b > c$, a contradiction$^*$.

---

$^*$ As a consequence of Proposition 1.18b) of Rudin, if $0 < x < y$, then $x^2 < xy$ (multiply both sides by $x$) and also $xy < y^2$ (multiply both sides by $y$). Therefore $x^2 < y^2$. An easy induction using this idea lets us conclude that $x^n < y^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N ^*$ whenever $0 < x < y$.

Comment: sorry if this is a dum question but how were you able "to raise both sides to the power $n$" if we don't know yet that such operation/function is monotone?

Comment: I guess in this case multiplying both sides by $c^{1/n}$ and then using the wrong assumption $b^{1/n}>c^{1/n}$ yields what we need. As in $b^{1/n} > c^{1/n}$ multiply both sides by $c^{1/n}$ yields $b^{1/n}(c^{1/n})^{n-1} > (c^{1/n})^n$ now using the starting assumption we get $ (b^{1/n})^n = (b^{1/n}(b^{1/n})^{n-1}>b^{1/n}(c^{1/n})^{n-1} > (c^{1/n})^n$, right?

Comment: @Pinocchio See the addendum I edited in. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think your answer makes sense on its own except for the fact that it does not answer me why if $t < r$ then $b^{t}$ when $t,r$ are rationals/fractions. I think I agree with what you wrote except the connection to my original question (sorry if Im being super dense).

Comment: @Pinocchio I'm adding on to what you've already done. Starting from $b^{t_1r_2} \leq b^{r_1t_2}$, all that is left is taking roots, as you've mentioned. In my answer, I'm explaining why taking roots preserves the ordering. Also, note that you can always take the denominators $r_2,t_2$ to be positive, so that you can always arrange for $t_1r_2 \leq r_1t_2$ to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$.  Then $b^n = b^n*1 < b^n*b = b^{n+1}$.  By transitivity of order and by induction, for $m,n \in \mathbb N$, $n < m \iff b^n < b^m$.

we can extend this to $n \in \mathbb Z$, as $b > 1 \implies \frac 1b < 1$ we have $b^n = b^n*1 < b^n*\frac 1b = b^{n-1}$ so by induction and transitivity of order, for $m,n \in \mathbb Z$, $n < m \iff b^n < b^m$.we can extend this to $n \in \mathbb Z$.

An aside:

For $b,c > 0$ and $ n \in \mathbb N$,  $b^n < c^n \iff b <c$ and in particular $b^n > 1 \iff b>1$.  This is easy to via induction as $b^n = b*.....*b < c*......*c = c^n \iff b < c$.

With that under our belts...

To extend to the rationals:

Remember $b^{\frac 1n}$ is the unique positive real $x$ so that $x^n = b$.  $x^n = b >  1$ so $x > 1$.

In Exercise 6b) has you proved that for $r = \frac mn; m, n \in \mathbb Z; n > 0 $ defining $b^r = (b^{\frac 1n})^m$ is well defined.

Then $r= \frac mn < s = \frac pq \iff mq < pn \iff b^r= b^{\frac mn} = (b^{\frac 1 {nq}})^{mq} < (b^{\frac 1{nq}})^{pn}= b^{\frac pq} = b^s$

Comment: are you sure $mq < pn$ is a true statement? $r,q$ could be negative rationals (or some part of it might be negative), or is the question only focused on positive rationals?

Comment: lets assume for a second that $mq < pn$ is true. Even if it were true, how did it even occur to you to do that last line? seem like it came out of nowhere to me :(

Comment: All rational numbers can be written as $m/n $ where m,n are integers and n >0.  If n,q >0 then m/n <p/q iff mq <pn.  That last line is simply expressing b^r and b^s as rationals with a common denomitator.  If r=mq/nq < s=pn/nq then mq < pn and c^mq < c^pn.  Let c=b^1/nq.  Then b^mq/nq<b^pn/nq.  It's not magic.

Comment: The most important part that I've glance over is proving Tha b^r= sqrt [n]{b}^m is well defined and consistant.  That is sqrt [n]{b}^m will always equal sqrt[nk]{b}^mk.  If you know that then r =m/n =mq/nq<s=p/q=pn/nq.  If we let c=sqrt[nq]{b} then we only have prove this is true for integers.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $b^{r} $ when $r$ is rational can be defined using algebraic processes and all its properties can be proved via algebra. The only part where we need analysis is the following theorem:

> If $b>0$ and $n$ is a positive integer then there is a unique positive real number $a$ such that $a^{n} =b$.

This theorem defines the symbol $b^{1/n}=a$ and if rational $r=m/n$ with $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}, n>0$ then we define $b^{r} =(b^{1/n})^{m}$.

The question assumes $b>1$ and two rationals $r, t$ with $t<r$ and we are supposed to prove $b^{t} <b^{r} $. This involves only algebra. One approach (the simpler one) is to let $p=r-t>0$ and then show that $b^{p} >1$. We have $p=m/n$ with $m, n$ as positive integers. And we can see that $b^{m} \geq b >1$ and hence taking $n$-th root we get $b^{p} >1$ and multiplying by positive number $b^{t}$ we get $b^{r} >b^{t} $.

The process of taking $n$-th roots preserves inequalities and technically we say that for any positive integer $n$ the function $f(x) =x^{1/n}$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$. The proof of this is dependent on the fact that $g(x) =x^{n} $ is strictly increasing for $x>0$. Moreover it is a very roundabout way to prove monotone nature of $f$ or $g$ via processes of calculus when the result is achieved via algebra.

The case for $g$ is simple. We have for positive $x, y$ $$\frac{x^{n}-y^{n}} {x-y} = x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1}>0$$ so that $x^{n} - y^{n} $ has same sign as $x-y$. This proves that $g$ is strictly increasing in $(0,\infty)$.

Next we deduce the increasing nature of $f$ from  that of $g$ via contradiction. Let $0<x<y$ and assume that $f(x) \geq f(y) $ that is $x^{1/n}\geq y^{1/n}$ and raising to power $n$ we get (via the strictly increasing nature of $g$) $x\geq y$ contrary to $x<y$. Hence we arrive at a contradiction and we must have $f(x) <f(y) $ so that $f$ is strictly increasing in $(0,\infty)$.

Whatever has been proved above involves algebraic manipulation of inequalities and the use of words like "monotone" or "strictly increasing" does not in anyway indicate the use of processes of analysis. Also understand that the above results are typically studied when one starts to learn surds and rational exponents in high school.